# Read one child node of the XML document

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, visual-studio-2010

My XML file looks like this:

```
<Root>
<ver>Test</ver>
</Root>
```

and this is my code:

```
Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml(xmlString)
Dim element = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ver")
Dim n1Element As System.Xml.XmlElement
MsgBox(n1Element.ChildNodes(0).InnerText)
```

What I am basically trying to achieve is displaying the `Test` string in the `MsgBox`.

For some reason I can not access the ChildNode(0) I think that the main problem here is the `System.Xml.XmlElement` but I dont have enough knowledge in this case.

What is wrong with this code and how can I access the `Test` string?

Comment: you haven't set `n1Element`, so accessing it will give problems..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

```
Dim n1Element = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Root/ver")
```